# Does prototype setAttribute works with element class selector

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am using prototype to change the onclick function of the button. The following code is working well.

```
$('button_id').setAttribute('onclick','test();');
```

but the following is not working

```
$$('div#divid button.buttonclass').setAttribute('onclick','test();'); or

$$('button.buttonclass').setAttribute('onclick','test();');
```

I just want to change the button `onclick` function. The button is inside a div element. Button has the class name `button` only and do not have the id attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$$('div#divid button.buttonclass')[0].setAttribute('onclick','test();');
```

Or

```
$$('button.buttonclass')[0].setAttribute('onclick','test();');
```

Class selector returns matching elements in form of ARRAY.